How to Batch imports Markdown documents to wiki.js website
I have written many markdown notes in Obsidian (including local pictures). Now I create a personal wiki website using Wiki.js (database is postgreSQL-16).
I wonder if it is possible to write a script to batch import .md documents to the wiki's website? And the script also can be used to synchronize data from each other.
I have very basic programing skills and hope the experts here can help me come up with an elegant solution, providing some general implementation steps, then I figure out the specific details myself. Thank you!

https://docs.requarks.io/en/editors/markdown suggest wiki.js supports markdown so are you asking how to batch import files?  Or do you want to transform the documents for use with wiki.js?  Do you know how to upload a document?

@AllanWind Q1: yes I am asking how to batch import files (maybe a script directly manipulate wiki.js's database. And also can be used to synchronize documents from obsidian to wiki). Q2&3, I don't want to transform files' format, yes I know how to manually upload a file through webpage.

https://feedback.js.wiki/wiki/p/ability-to-bulk-upload-pages has a couple of suggestions and there is a pointer to project that does a sync with Dokuwiki that might be of interest to you.  As it stands you are question lacks focus.
